# Raspberry PI SD card in read only mode or is it broken?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, sd-card

yesterday I couldn't open Portainer which lead me into investigating my Raspberry Pi which is running an Ubuntu Server. After I logged in trough SSH I tried updating my PI but I've got a message that the Filesystem is read only, so I rebooted to system.
Unfortunate this lead to a complete failure because the PI was not booting probably and I connected it to a Monitor and keyboard to see what's wrong. (Before that I took a backup of the SD Card). I was in a Initframe shell or something, but I tried fixing it with `fsck -fy /dev/sdb2` but this gives me the error "

```
fsck.ext4: unable to set superblock flags on writeable
Wrtitable:************ WARING: Filesystem still has errors **********
```

After that I connected the PI sc card to my main system and tried to change the cmdline.txt entering rm before rootwait, which did nothing because after I disconnected the SD card it went back to normal. I also couldn't delete any volumes or anything else.

I could run e2fsck -b 8193 or 31768 but when I try this It's only saying that:

```
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying open /dev/sdb2
```

What could I try next? Or is it helpless?

Comment: Once an SD card starts to fail like this then the best you can do is replace it